# Can you use a 2 terminal furnace gas valve on a 4 terminal furnace gas valve?

Tags: furnace, valve

How can I hook up a 2  wire terminal furnace gas valve to a 4 wire terminal furnace gas valve? Why are there 2 wire and 4 wire terminal furnace gas valves

Comment: it'd help if you gave us make/model info for the valves in question as well as a wiring diagram for your furnace...